# redis as write-back view count cache for mysql

Tags: mysql, caching, redis

I have a very high throughput site for which I'm trying to store "view counts" for each page in a mySQL database (for legacy reasons they must ultimately end up in mySQL).

The sheer number of views is making it impractical to do SQL "UPDATE ITEM SET VIEW_COUNT=VIEW_COUNT+1" type of statements.  There are millions of items but most are only viewed a small number of times,  others are viewed many times.

So I'm considering using Redis to gather the view counts,  with a background thread that writes the counts to mySQL.    What is the recommended method for doing this?    There are some issues with the approach:

- how often does the background thread run?
- how does it determine what to write back to mySQL?
- should I store a Redis KEY for every ITEM that gets hit?
- what TTL should I use?
- is there already some pre-built solution or powerpoint presentation that gets me halfway there, etc.

I have seen very similar questions on StackOverflow but none with a great answer...yet!   Hoping there's more Redis knowledge out there at this point.

Comment: Hi guys,  the answers provided have been VERY instructive.    I realize there may be problems with a couple of them but I'm thumbsing them up for starters because the ideas and discussion have been great.

Comment: In the end the pure coding is just a few lines, the "complication" arises (as usual) from the "what-if"s, i.e. the error cases. It would be fun to write the actual code. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to step back and look at some of your questions from a different angle to get to your answers.

"how often does the background thread run?"
To answer this you need to answer these questions: How much data can you lose? What is the reason for the data being in MySQL, and how often is that data accessed?  For example, if the DB is only needed to be consulted once per day for a report, you might only need it to be updated once per day. On the other hand, what if the Redis instance dies? How many increments can you lose and still be "ok"? These will provide the answers to the question of how often to update your MySQL instance and aren't something we can answer for you.

I would use a very different strategy for storing this in redis. For the sake of the discussion let us assume you decide you need to "flush to db" every hour.

Store each hit in hashes with a key name structure along these lines:

```
interval_counter:DD:HH
interval_counter:total
```

Use the page id (such as MD5 sum of the URI, the URI itself, or whatever ID you currently use) as the hash key and do two increments on a page view; one for each hash. This provides you with a current total for each page and a subset of pages to be updated.

You would then have your cron job run a minute or so after the start of the hour to pull down all pages with updated view counts by grabbing the previous hour's hash. This provides you with a very fast means of getting the data to update the MySQL DB with while avoiding any need to do math or play tricks with timestamps etc..  By pulling data from a key which is no longer bing incremented you avoid race conditions due to clock skew.

You could set an expiration on the daily key, but I'd rather use the cron job to delete it when it has successfully updated the DB. This means your data is still there if the cron job fails or fails to be executed. It also provides the front-end with a full set of known hit counter data via keys that do not change. If you wanted, you could even keep the daily data around to be able to do window views of how popular a page is. For example if you kept the daily hash around for 7 days by setting an expire via the cron job instead of a delete, you could display how much traffic each page has had per day for the last week.

Executing two hincr operations can be done either solo or pipelined still performs quite well and is more efficient than doing calculations and munging data in code.

Now for the question of expiring the low traffic pages vs memory use. First, your data set doesn't sound like one which will require huge amounts of memory. Of course, much of that depends on how you identify each page. If you have a numerical ID the memory requirements will be rather small. If you still wind up with too much memory, you can tune it via the config, and if needs be could even use a 32 bit compile of redis for a significant memory use reduction. For example, the data I describe in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029195/scalable-way-of-logging-page-request-data-from-a-php-application/6049688#6049688) I used to manage for one of the ten busiest forums on the Internet and it consumed less than 3GB of data. I also stored the counters in far more "temporal window" keys than I am describing here.

That said, in this use case Redis is the cache. If you are still using too much memory after the above options you could set an expiration on keys and add an expire command to each ht. More specifically, if you follow the above pattern you will be doing the following per hit:

```
hincr -> total
hincr -> daily
expire -> total
```

This lets you keep anything that is actively used fresh by extending it's expiration every time it is accessed. Of course, to do this you'd need to wrap your display call to catch the null answer for hget on the totals hash and populate it from the MySQL DB, then increment. You could even do both as an increment. This would preserve the above structure and would likely be the same codebase needed to update the Redis server from the MySQL Db if you the Redis node needed repopulation. For that you'll need to consider and decide which data source will be considered authoritative.

You can tune the cron job's performance by modifying your interval in accordance with the parameters of data integrity you determine from the earlier questions. To get a faster running cron nob you decrease the window. With this method decreasing the window means you should have a smaller collection of pages to update. A big advantage here is you don't need to figure out what keys you need to update and then go fetch them. you can do an hgetall and iterate over the hash's keys to do updates. This also saves many round trips by retrieving all the data at once. In either case if you will likely want to consider a second Redis instance slaved to the first to do your reads from. You would still do deletes against the master but those operations are much quicker and less likely to introduce delays in your write-heavy instance.

If you need disk persistence of the Redis DB, then certainly put that on a slave instance. Otherwise if you do have a lot of data being changed often your RDB dumps will be constantly running.

I hope that helps. There are no "canned" answers because to use Redis properly you need to think first about how you will access the data, and that differs greatly from user to user and project to project. Here I based the route taken on this description: two consumers accessing the data, one to display only and the other to determine updating another datasource.

Comment: 1. Normally redis doesn't lose all data on a shutdown, but in a tuneable interval writes a file  // 2. with calculation I meant to get Hour and Minute - I can imagine that getting the current hour / minute might be real work (daylight saving etc. involved) when done billions of times // 3. I am happy that a programmer of a real big use case with redis suggests more or less the same solution as my theoretical thoughts ;-)

Comment: I'm well aware of Redis' persistence. My references to what if it goes down are not about simple restarts of the Redis service. For example if the Redis box dies due to disk failure how does this impact the SLA and authority for data? While the tunable is there, it is mostly irrelevant with updates on the order described. If you have thousands of updates per second your either update every second or you spend a lot of time saving many many thousands per minute and hope it doesn't overlap. With many thousands of changes per second you really need to pay attention to the tradeoff.

Answer (score 3):

Consolidation of my other answer:

Define a time-interval in which the transfer from redis to mysql should happen, i.e. minute, hour or day. Define it in a way so that fast and easyly an identifying key can be obtained. This key must be ordered, i.e. a smaller time should give a smaller key.

Let it be hourly and the key be `YYYYMMDD_HH` for readability.

Define a prefix like "hitcount_".

Then for every time-interval you set a hash `hitcount_<timekey>` in redis which contains all requested items of that interval in the form ITEM => count.

There exists two parts of the solution:

1. The actual page that has to count:

   a) get the current `$timekey`, i.e. by date- functions

   b) get the value of `$ITEM`

   b) send the redis-command `HINCRBY hitcount_$timekey $ITEM 1`
2. A cronjob which runs in that given interval, not too close to the limit of that intervals (in example: not at the full hour). This cronjob:

   a) Extracts the current time-key (for now it would be 20130527_08)

   b) Requests all matching keys from redis with `KEYS hitcount_*` (those should be a small number)

   c) compares every such hash against the current `hitcount_<timekey>`

   d) if that key is smaller than current key, then process it as `$processing_key`:

   - read all pairs ITEM => counter by `HGETALL $processing_key` as $item, $cnt
   - update the database with `UPDATE ITEM SET VIEW_COUNT=VIEW_COUNT+$cnt where ITEM=$item"
   - delete that key from the hash by `HDEL $processing_key $item`
   - no need to del the hash itself - there are no empty hashes in redis as far as I tried

If you want to have a TTL involved, say if the cleanup-cronjob may be not reliable (as might not run for many hours), then you could create the future hashes by the cronjob with an appropriate TTL, that means for now we could create a hash 20130527_09 with ttl 10 hours, 20130527_10 with TTL 11 hours, 20130527_11 with TTL 12 hours. Problem is that you would need a pseudokey, because empty hashes seem to be deleted automatically.

Answer (score 1):

See EDIT3 for current state of the A...nswer.

I would write a key for every ITEM. A few tenthousand keys are definitely no problem at all.

Do the pages change very much? I mean do you get a lot of pages that will never be called again? Otherwise I would simply:

- add the value for an ITEM on page request.
- every minute or 5 minutes call a cronjob that reads the redis-keys, read the value (say 7) and reduce it by decrby ITEM 7. In MySQL you could increment the value for that ITEM  by 7.

If you have a lot of pages/ITEMS which will never be called again you could make a cleanup-job once a day to delete keys with value 0. This should be locked against incrementing that key again from the website.

I would set no TTL at all, so the values should live forever. You could check the memory usage, but I see a lot of different possible pages with current GB of memory.

EDIT: incr is very nice for that, because it sets the key if not set before.

EDIT2: Given the large amount of different pages, instead of the slow "keys *" command you could use HASHES with incrby (http://redis.io/commands/hincrby). Still I am not sure if HGETALL is much faster then KEYS *, and a HASH does not allow a TTL for single keys.

EDIT3: Oh well, sometimes the good ideas come late. It is so simple: Just prefix the key with a timeslot (say day-hour) or make a HASH with name "requests_". Then no overlapping of delete and increment may happen! Every hour you take the possible keys with older "day_hour_*" - values, update the MySQL and delete those old keys. The only condition is that your servers are not too different on their clock, so use UTC and synchronized servers, and don't start the cron at x:01 but x:20 or so.

That means: a called page converts a call of ITEM1 at 23:37, May 26 2013 to Hash 20130526_23, ITEM1. `HINCRBY count_20130526_23 ITEM1 1`

One hour later the list of `keys count_*` is checked, and all up to `count_20130523` are processed (read key-value by hgetall, update mysql), and deleted one by one after processing (hdel). After finishing that you check if hlen is 0 and del count_...

So you only have a small amount of keys (one per unprocessed hour), that makes `keys count_*` fast, and then process the actions of that hour. You can give a TTL of a few hours, if your cron is delayed or timejumped or down for a while or something like that.

Comment: thanks,  i think this won't quite work,  there are a few billion  so they probably need to have TTLs on them.   there are probably only a couple of million distinct per day though.  i do like the "decrement by 7" approach,  would decrease the number of updates dramatically.

Comment: Then I would make a TTL a few times (10x) as long as the "transfer to database" - time. The problem with deleting an "unused" entry is the risk that it is incremented just before the deletion. Do you mean a few billion _different_ requests, or just a few billion requests at all?

Comment: @OneSolitaryNoob: One point is to decrease the number of `update`- Statements, the other is to get it out of the responsetime- process. A cron has plenty of times, it even could take seconds. ;-)

Comment: I think this solution is far from being efficient / correct.
unless i dont see how you do it without using KEYS

Comment: Yeah, the "keys" command itself is very slow, it may take 0.1 or even 1 seconds with the given number of distinct pages (which surprised me). Yet it is working outside user-action (in a cron) and is much faster than all those single update-statements. For that big number I also would think about a hash instead of single keys. But a hash has no TTL!

Comment: Consider SCAN over KEYS, but both are non optimal :)